# Android DataInputStream skip frame if too slow

Tags: java, android, networking, stream

I am using [this MjpegInputStream](https://bitbucket.org/neuralassembly/simplemjpegview/src/a4487b3e6a966db14742e40ef44691ece8475eda/src/com/camera/simplemjpeg/MjpegInputStream.java?at=master) which is using a DataInputStream to read a video stream. Sometimes things went wrong and the video gets a hugh delay. Data from the input stream bluks up maybe because of network delay. I would like to skip some frames in this case but I am unable to detect it.

I tried to use `DataInputStream .available()` in the [main loop](https://bitbucket.org/neuralassembly/simplemjpegview/src/a4487b3e6a966db14742e40ef44691ece8475eda/src/com/camera/simplemjpeg/MjpegView.java?at=master#cl-133) but that did not work because it is always below 8000. Looks like data is queued up somewhere else. Network stack?

Is there are network buffer in front of DataInputStream? How can get the size of the incoming data that is not processed yet?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the problem was mainly the bad network connection. Everything works fine as long there is not a big packet lost. I solved it be creating a [Wi-Fi direct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct) connection between both devices.

Fun fact: With an active Wi-Fi direct connection you can still connect to a normal wifi hotspot. This way you create two connections what is normally not possible.